# How to also animate subview in navigation bar?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a subview in my navigation bar. I try to add it by this way:

```
  UIView *customView =
  [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:
                  CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width + label.frame.size.width, 44)];
  UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
  [customView addSubview:imageView];
  [customView addSubview:label];
  [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:customView];
```

However, when I try to push the navigation bar, the customView stays in the place, not animating following the sliding navigation bar. How can I achieve the animated subview? Is it even possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not add subview in that way
you have tospecify your view location in the **left , right or title view**

> self.navigationItem.titleView = YOURVIEW;

or choose another location left or right  items in this way the the title view will added to the current view if you want to remove it just set it to nil in the place you want and reload it subviews again,

> self.navigationItem.titleView = nil;

Comment: That's right this is the correct way to add a subview on navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

As you are using

```
  [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:customView];
```

that means the navigation bar you have create is in App delegate and is common for all the viewControllers in your project,that is why once you add a view on to it you see it on every view you have. Remove your sub-view in

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
[Your subview remove fromSuperView]; 
[super viewWillDisappear:YES];
}
```

and add that subview in

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:Your subview];

 [super viewWillAppear:YES];

}
```

this will add the subview in that particular view only and remove it as soon as that view is popped or pushed.The code given is not correct to the syntax please give a check on that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I'll accept Omar's answer because it's a better way to add a custom subview to navigation bar :)